# How to get the params from a saved XGBoost model

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to train a XGBoost model using the params below:

```
xgb_params = {
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'eval_metric': 'auc',
    'lambda': 0.8,
    'alpha': 0.4,
    'max_depth': 10,
    'max_delta_step': 1,
    'verbose': True
}
```

Since my input data is too big to be fully loaded into the memory, I adapt the incremental training:

```
xgb_clf = xgb.train(xgb_params, input_data, num_boost_round=rounds_per_batch,
                    xgb_model=model_path)
```

The code for prediction is

```
xgb_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
booster = xgb.Booster()
booster.load_model(model_path)
xgb_clf._Booster = booster
raw_probas = xgb_clf.predict_proba(x)
```

The result seemed good. But when I tried to invoke `xgb_clf.get_xgb_params()`, I got a param dict in which all params were set to default values.

I can guess that the root cause is when I initialized the model, I didn't pass any params in. So the model was initialized using the default values but when it predicted, it used an internal booster that had been fitted using some pre-defined params.

However, I wonder is there any way that, after I assign a pre-trained booster model to a XGBClassifier, I can see the real params that are used to train the booster, but not those which are used to initialize the classifier.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be mixing the sklearn API with the functional API in your code, if you stick to either one you should get the parameters to persist in the pickle. Here's an example using the sklearn API.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits


digits = load_digits(2)
y = digits['target']
X = digits['data']

xgb_params = {
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'reg_lambda': 0.8,
    'reg_alpha': 0.4,
    'max_depth': 10,
    'max_delta_step': 1,
}
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(**xgb_params)
clf.fit(X, y, eval_metric='auc', verbose=True)

pickle.dump(clf, open("xgb_temp.pkl", "wb"))
clf2 = pickle.load(open("xgb_temp.pkl", "rb"))

assert np.allclose(clf.predict(X), clf2.predict(X))
print(clf2.get_xgb_params())
```

which produces

```
{'base_score': 0.5,
 'colsample_bylevel': 1,
 'colsample_bytree': 1,
 'gamma': 0,
 'learning_rate': 0.1,
 'max_delta_step': 1,
 'max_depth': 10,
 'min_child_weight': 1,
 'missing': nan,
 'n_estimators': 100,
 'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 'reg_alpha': 0.4,
 'reg_lambda': 0.8,
 'scale_pos_weight': 1,
 'seed': 0,
 'silent': 1,
 'subsample': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used to use sklearn's joblib.dump before and it did work. But I didn't manage to find a way to fit the model incrementally using sklearn API. Therefore could you please kindly let me know how to do it? (The need to fit the model incrementally is much more important)

Comment: I don't think you can do incremental learning using scikt-learn API. You can do it using xgboost functional API

Comment: What's the get_xgb_params like api in functional/Native API?

Answer (score 2):

If you are training like this -

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_train, label=y_train)
model = xgb.train(model_params, dtrain, model_num_rounds)
```

Then the model returned is a [Booster](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster).

```
import json
json.loads(model.save_config())
```

the [model.save_config()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.save_config) function lists down model parameters in addition to other configurations.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @ytsaig's answer, if you are using `early_stopping_rounds` argument in `clf.fit()` method then certain additional parameters are generated but not returned as part of `clf.get_xgb_params()` method. These can be accessed directly as follows: `clf.best_score`, `clf.best_iteration` and `clf.best_ntree_limit`.

Ref: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit